# How to prevent cache busting (preferably on a single section)?

Tags: cache

I have a template that displays 1,100 entries as dots on a zoomable/searchable map. The query is cached and it performs beautifully. As expected, if I edit any of those entries the cache is busted and the next page load lags.

What I prefer to do is have the cache rebuilt once per day via a cron job or some other method.

For starters, I added

```
'cacheElementQueries' => false,
```

to my general config. I thought this prevents automatic cache busting, but it does not seem to. If I edit an entry, the cache is still being rebuilt (or so I assume by the page load time).

Any help on what I'm not understanding? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cacheElementQueries` set to `false` should cause the behavior you're looking for. i.e. Craft no longer keeps track of element queries inside of the cache tag for use in when deciding when to bust them.

Might also be worth looking at the [Cache Flag](https://plugins.craftcms.com/cache-flag) plugin as that lets you more explicitly define when you'd like caches to be busted.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why, but with cacheElementQueries set to false I'm still seeing a load lag after I edit one of the related entries to my query.  Would '{% cache **unless** .... %}' be affecting anything?

Comment: What I found:  even with cacheElementQueries set to FALSE the cache will be busted when an entry is edited if  `{% cache *unless* .... %}` is used in the cache statement. Maybe that makes sense, but I'm just working around it by changing the query so I do not need the *cache unless*